# Access keys not working inside popup (WPF)

Tags: wpf, popup, access-keys

I have a simple popup in my WPF application.
There is a button with access-key inside this popup.

The problem I have is that this button doesn't respond to Alt+access-key combination.
Moreover pressing Alt doesn't make access key visible like it happens in ordinary window.

Is there any way to make controls inside popup respond to Alt+access-key combination?

P.S. I have no problem with navigation using Tab through this popup.

Sapmle code that I'm using

```
     <Grid>
        <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Content="_Open File"></Button>
        <Popup x:Name="Popup" StaysOpen="False">
            <Grid Background="White">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Button Content="_Open File"/>
                <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="O_pen File"/>
                <CheckBox Grid.Row="2" Content="_Go"></CheckBox>
            </Grid>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
```

```
    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      Popup.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

I have also tried adding this as the first answer suggests

```
    private void Popup_OnOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      var popup = sender as Popup;
      popup.Child.Focusable = true;
      Keyboard.Focus(popup.Child);
    }
```

I have also tried the idea from the first comment

```
    private void Popup_OnOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      var popup = sender as Popup;
      FocusManager.SetIsFocusScope(popup, true);
    }
```

or instead of standart focus scope the one from suggested link [codeproject.com/Articles/38507/Using-the-WPF-FocusScope](https://codeproject.com/Articles/38507/Using-the-WPF-FocusScope)

```
   EnhancedFocusScope.SetFocusOnActiveElementInScope(popup);
```

Setting focus scope helped a little bit, but I didn't manage to make it work exactly as I would like.
Setting focus scope to true did help to use alt+key combination for checkboxes and label+textbox, but not for buttons. Although I could use Alt+access key combinations, I couldn't actually see them, because underscores didn't appear when I pressed Alt

Comment: A popup is a separate window. That means it has it's own focus scope. You need a control to be in what wpf thinks of as a focus scope before these keys will work. You could try seting focusmanager.isfocusscope on your popup once visible. Or put your commands in the main window. Or try the approach here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38507/Using-the-WPF-FocusScope

Comment: Can you add a minimum code sample that demonstrates how you open the popup and how the button in question is created?

Comment: @sa.he I have added some minimum code to my question

Answer (score 1):

`Popup` is not part of the visual tree. This means it has its own isolated focus scope. When a `Popup` is opened, the `Popup.Child` is hosted in a dedicated `Window` with its own detached visual tree. The `Popup.Child` therefore needs to explicitly receive keyboard focus before the access keys are available in the detached focus scope.

You can handle the `Popup.Opened` event, either in code-behind or using an attached behavior.
It's essential that the `Popup.Child` is focusable in order to receive keyboard focus.
Some classes like `Panel` and its subclasses have `UIElement.Focusable` set to `false` by default.

```
<StackPanel>
  <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton" Content="Show Popup" />
  <Popup x:Name="Popup" 
        AllowsTransparency="True"  
        PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=ToggleButton}" 
        IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=ToggleButton, Path=IsChecked}" 
        Opened="Popup_OnOpened">
    <StackPanel>
      <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="O_pen File" />
      <CheckBox Grid.Row="2" Content="_Go" />
    </StackPanel>
  </Popup>
</StackPanel>

private void Popup_OnOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var popup = sender as Popup;
  popup.Child.Focusable = true;
  Keyboard.Focus(popup.Child);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I have tried this code in a separate application and it doesn't seem to help with my problem, it helps to set focus on popup first item, but Alt+key inside popup still doesn't work

Comment: I have tested your posted code and it works: I was able to check the `CheckBox` using the access key e.g. Alt + G. Note that your posted example is not registering the `Popup.Opened` event callback. I have updated my example to meet your posted code.

Comment: I have in my code `Opened="Popup_OnOpened"`. What about buttons, do they react on their Alt+key? I have mentioned in my question that I have managed to mark checkboxed with Alt+key, but buttons don't respond. Another problem is that I need access key underlines to apper, when Alt is pressed alone. It happens when focus is on main control, but when focus is on popup they don\t appear

Comment: Yes it works with buttons too. The issue regarding the visibility of the accelerator key must be related to some low level code. This access key feature is a Windows controlled feature. WPF only offers an API to define and handle access key commands. There is no API to e.g. manipulate the design or behavior of those keys. I'm pretty sure the internally created window for the `Popup` breaks this behavior. I have not done any investigation if it is possible to "hack" this behavior.

Comment: `Popup` excels when it comes to positioning. It allows be docked to any element and is rendered on top of *any* object on the screen. The docking is just a simple initial placement: the `Popup` won't follow when the placement target moves e.g. when the window was moved. Focus contexts get broken, visual tree gets broken.

Comment: Depending on the use case, you should consider to create a custom popup, e.g., by using a simple `Grid` and toggle its visibility to show/hide it. This would be much more lightweight. Such a solution would keep the focus scopes and visual tree intact. If you are trying to implement  a simple drop down consider to use the customizable `Expander` control, which is a lightweight popup in tandem with a toggle button.

Comment: thank you, I think switching to custom Expander is the best idea, I was thinking about it myself, but hoped that there was some way to deal with popups

Answer (score 0):

Once a button or a checkbox inside the popup is focused, the alt-shortcuts works.

```
<Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Content="_Open File" />
<Popup x:Name="Popup">
    <StackPanel Background="White">
        <CheckBox x:Name="FirstCeckbox" Content="_Foo" />
        <CheckBox Content="_Bar" />
    </StackPanel>
</Popup>
```

Code behind:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Popup.IsOpen = !Popup.IsOpen;
    if (Popup.IsOpen)
        FirstCeckbox.Focus();  // Make sure to focus a Button or a Checkbox, not the Stackpanel or Grid etc.
}
```